# Android HttpClient SLOW

Tags: android, html, performance, httpclient, httpurlconnection

i am currently working on an android app which includes a HTML-code-download feauture. However, the execution via HttpClient is very slow and takes about 12 seconds for a page which loads in 1 or 2 seconds via phone browser. I already tried using HttpURLConnection, but it downloads the code in roughly the same time. What would you peoplerecommend me changing?

```
public class Downloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{

 protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
 {
    String url = params[0];
    String htmlcode = "FAIL";


        try{

            Log.i("METAMETER","DL: INITIALIZING");
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();            
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpParams httpParameters = client.getParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 1000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 1000);

            Log.i("METAMETER","DL: EXECUTING");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
             //Apparently the step above takes about 12 seconds for a page which only takes 1-2 seconds via browser
            Log.i("METAMETER","DL: WRITING");
            htmlcode = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


         }catch (Exception e){htmlcode = "EXCEPTION";}
        Log.i("METAMETER","DL: DONE");
  return htmlcode;
  }        
}
```

Comment: I recommend that you use Traceview and determine precisely where your problem lies.

Comment: Ok, I just used Traceview for the first time, what do you want to know?

Comment: What I can see is that there is a ~9-second-gap until the AsyncTask starts working. In this time period there is no activity anywhere. Afterwards, the AsyncTask works for 1,5 seconds. However, also here there are many small gaps.

Comment: "What I can see is that there is a ~9-second-gap until the AsyncTask starts working" -- that would suggest that your problem is not in this code, but with the task itself. Are you using `executeOnExecutor()` to run it?

Comment: That was what I was thinking of at first too. However, the log entry "DL: EXECUTING" shows up very fast, which means, that the AsyncTask actually runs fine. In Fact, the LogCat is evidence for the 12 second delay lying within 
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

Try using

```
HttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("MyApp/1.0");
```

Comment: I did, but unfortunately there was no noticable difference